# Cannot figure out how to play my record with React - Mic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webm

I am working on a project for which the user have to record something and then he has the option to hear it.

I installed react-mic from npmjs.com :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mic

In the above link they shared a demo: 
https://hackingbeauty.github.io/react-mic/

The demo has the option to record, stop and eventually **play** your record.

I managed to implement the start and stop buttons, the recording seems to work fine but I do not understand two things:

1. Where is this record being saved?
2. After pressing the "Stop" button, there is a blobURL in the console. I assume that the record is saved to that blob, but how can I reach it? copy pasting the blobURL does not work.

My code looks exactly like their suggestion in npmjs.com

```
    startRecording = () => {
      this.setState({record: true});
    }
    stopRecording = () => {
      this.setState({record: false});
    }
    onData(recordedBlob) {
      console.log('chunk of real-time data is: ', recordedBlob);
    }

    onStop(recordedBlob) {
      console.log('recordedBlob is: ', recordedBlob);
    }


    render(){
       return(
         <div>
         <ReactMic
                record = {this.state.record}
                className = "sound-wave"
                onStop = {this.onStop}
                onData = {this.onData}
                strokeColor="#009900"
                backgroundColor="#FF8990"/><br/>
              <button onClick = {this.startRecording}>start</button>
              <button onClick = {this.stopRecording}>stop</button>  
              <MusicPlayer playlist = {SongChallenge}/> </div>
     )
    }
```

Thanks in advance.